# how to use bluetooth headset on pc

Tags: bluetooth

i have a bluetooth headset for my phone, but use skype quite a lot and was wanting toi know how to use my headset for my pc to make it wireless. i have a bluetooth adaptor for my pc installed, and blue soleil, but it only seems to pick up the phone

Comment: with what operating system?

Comment: Interesting.  Have also wanted to do this.  Question 70347 indicates it is doable but no direction

Comment: @John T- given the OP mentions Blue Soleil, I'm guessing Windows.

Comment: Yeah but giving advice on navigating control panel is different for XP & 7 for example :\

Comment: As John T points out, it would be easier if we knew the OS and OS version.  It might also help to know what the Bluetooth headset is.

Answer (score 2):

Typically discovery does not have to be enabled on the desktop, the desktop will discover the device, rather than the other way around. Ensure the headset is **on** and it is set as **visible**. Ensure your bluetooth USB adapter is also **on**.

In **Control Panel -> Sounds and Audio Devices** (**Control Panel -> Sound for Vista+**) , set the audio and voice device to your Bluetooth headset (it should be picked up if the above is followed).

For a thorough walkthrough, O'Reilly has [a great article on Getting Your Bluetooth Headset to Work in XP](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/archive/bluetooth.html?page=1).

Answer (score 0):

The help isn't particularly helpful:

> Steps:
>
> 1. Connect to the *Bluetooth* enabled headset.
> 2. Play music on your computer or chat using network meeting tools. You may need to press a multifunction button on your headset to transmit audio between the computer and the headset.

Make sure that the headset is turned on and broadcasting it's ID.

The right most icon in Blue Soleil is the Headset service - does that do anything when you click it?

You might have to click "My Bluetooth > Bluetooth Device Discovery"